# how to use a procedure with Default parameter in gridview ASP.NET VS in sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, gridview, sqldatasource

I want to use a stored procedure that can make some parameters with null value and then test it if the parameter is null or not and do some coding , the procedure  is working fine ... but when i want to use it in gridview in sqldatasource mode assistant it works too .... but wen i run my web page it shows an empty gridview 
in the first execute the sqldatasource will fill the procedure with just one value wich it : @nomgiac from a session variable

and then when i want to search it fill the procedure with 3 parameters .. just to shiw me an another results

note even if the results is difrrent but it returning the same queries

This is the stored procedure

```
 create proc rechercherGIACetAffiche @nomgiac varchar(20),@nom varchar(30) = null,@par varchar(50) = null
           as
            begin
            IF @nom is null and @par is null
                begin
                    select [ID_Dossier] as 'ID_Dossier'
                      ,[ID_Entreprise] as 'ID_Entreprise'
                      ,[Date_Depot] as 'Date_Dépôt'
                      ,[Type_Etude] as 'Type_Etude'
                      ,[Dernier_Type] as 'Dernier_Type'
                      ,[Eligibile] as 'Eligibilité'
                      ,[Fiche_Information] as 'Fiche_Information'
                      ,[Buletin_Adhesion] as 'Bulletin_d’adhésion'
                      ,[Fiche_Renseignment] as 'Fiche_Renseignment'
                      ,[Attestation] as 'Attestation'
                      ,[Date_Debut] as 'Date_Début'
                      ,[Date_Fin] as 'Date_Fin'
                      ,[ID_Cabinet] as 'ID_Cabinet'
                      ,[Montant_Demander] as 'Montant_Demander'
                      ,[Duree] as 'Durée'
                      ,[Porcentage_Taux] as 'Pourcentage,Taux' from Dossier where Nom_Giac = @nomgiac
                      return 
                end
            if  @par is not null and @nom='CNSS' 
              begin
              select d.[ID_Dossier] as 'ID_Dossier'
              ,d.[ID_Entreprise] as 'ID_Entreprise'
              ,[Date_Depot] as 'Date_Dépôt'
              ,[Type_Etude] as 'Type_Etude'
              ,[Dernier_Type] as 'Dernier_Type'
              ,[Eligibile] as 'Eligibilité'
              ,[Fiche_Information] as 'Fiche_Information'
              ,[Buletin_Adhesion] as 'Bulletin_d’adhésion'
              ,[Fiche_Renseignment] as 'Fiche_Renseignment'
              ,[Attestation] as 'Attestation'
              ,[Date_Debut] as 'Date_Début'
              ,[Date_Fin] as 'Date_Fin'
              ,[ID_Cabinet] as 'ID_Cabinet'
              ,[Montant_Demander] as 'Montant_Demander'
              ,[Duree] as 'Durée'
              ,[Porcentage_Taux] as 'Pourcentage,Taux' 
              from dbo.Dossier d inner join entreprise e on d.ID_Entreprise=e.ID_Entreprise
              where CNSS_Entreprise=@par and d.Nom_Giac=@nomgiac 
              return 
              end

            else if @par is not null and @nom='RS'  
              begin
              select [ID_Dossier] as 'ID_Dossier'
              ,[ID_Entreprise] as 'ID_Entreprise'
              ,[Date_Depot] as 'Date_Dépôt'
              ,[Type_Etude] as 'Type_Etude'
              ,[Dernier_Type] as 'Dernier_Type'
              ,[Eligibile] as 'Eligibilité'
              ,[Fiche_Information] as 'Fiche_Information'
              ,[Buletin_Adhesion] as 'Bulletin_d’adhésion'
              ,[Fiche_Renseignment] as 'Fiche_Renseignment'
              ,[Attestation] as 'Attestation'
              ,[Date_Debut] as 'Date_Début'
              ,[Date_Fin] as 'Date_Fin'
              ,[ID_Cabinet] as 'ID_Cabinet'
              ,[Montant_Demander] as 'Montant_Demander'
              ,[Duree] as 'Durée'
              ,[Porcentage_Taux] as 'Pourcentage,Taux'  
              from dbo.Dossier 
              where  Nom_Giac=@nomgiac and ID_Entreprise in( select ID_Entreprise
                                                             from dbo.Entreprise
                                                             where Raison_Social=@par) 
                                                             return                                            
              end
           else if @par is not null and @nom ='Date'
            begin
             declare @v smalldatetime,@b smalldatetime
              set @b=SUBSTRING(@par,1,4)
              set @v=SUBSTRING(@par,5,8)
            select [ID_Dossier] as 'ID_Dossier'
              ,[ID_Entreprise] as 'ID_Entreprise'
              ,[Date_Depot] as 'Date_Dépôt'
              ,[Type_Etude] as 'Type_Etude'
              ,[Dernier_Type] as 'Dernier_Type'
              ,[Eligibile] as 'Eligibilité'
              ,[Fiche_Information] as 'Fiche_Information'
              ,[Buletin_Adhesion] as 'Bulletin_d’adhésion'
              ,[Fiche_Renseignment] as 'Fiche_Renseignment'
              ,[Attestation] as 'Attestation'
              ,[Date_Debut] as 'Date_Début'
              ,[Date_Fin] as 'Date_Fin'
              ,[ID_Cabinet] as 'ID_Cabinet'
              ,[Montant_Demander] as 'Montant_Demander'
              ,[Duree] as 'Durée'
              ,[Porcentage_Taux] as 'Pourcentage,Taux'  
            from Dossier 
            where Date_Depot between @b and @v and Nom_Giac like @nomgiac
            return 
            end 
            end
```

and tis is the sqldatasoure code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DOSIIER_RECHERCHE_ET_AFFICHE" runat="server" 
                     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OfficeConnectionString %>" 
                     SelectCommand="rechercherGIACetAffiche" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                     <SelectParameters>
                         <asp:SessionParameter Name="nomgiac" SessionField="Nom_GIAC" Type="String" />
                         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="RecherhcerComboBox" DefaultValue="" Name="nom" 
                             PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                         <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="par" SessionField="Recherche" 
                             Type="String" />
                     </SelectParameters>
                 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and this is the grid view :

```
<asp:GridView  ID="DossierGV" runat="server" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
                        DataKeyNames="ID_Dossier" PageSize="5" 
                              DataSourceID="DOSIIER_RECHERCHE_ET_AFFICHE" >
                             <Columns>
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Dossier" HeaderText="ID_Dossier" ReadOnly="True" 
                                  SortExpression="ID_Dossier" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Entreprise" HeaderText="ID_Entreprise" 
                                  SortExpression="ID_Entreprise" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Dépôt" HeaderText="Date_Dépôt" 
                                  SortExpression="Date_Dépôt" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Etude" HeaderText="Type_Etude" 
                                  SortExpression="Type_Etude" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Dernier_Type" HeaderText="Dernier_Type" 
                                  SortExpression="Dernier_Type" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Eligibilité" HeaderText="Eligibilité" 
                                  SortExpression="Eligibilité" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Fiche_Information" HeaderText="Fiche_Information" 
                                  SortExpression="Fiche_Information" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Bulletin_d’adhésion" HeaderText="Bulletin_d’adhésion" 
                                  SortExpression="Bulletin_d’adhésion" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Fiche_Renseignment" HeaderText="Fiche_Renseignment" 
                                  SortExpression="Fiche_Renseignment" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Attestation" HeaderText="Attestation" 
                                  SortExpression="Attestation" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Début" HeaderText="Date_Début" 
                                  SortExpression="Date_Début" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Fin" HeaderText="Date_Fin" 
                                  SortExpression="Date_Fin" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Cabinet" HeaderText="ID_Cabinet" 
                                  SortExpression="ID_Cabinet" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Montant_Demander" HeaderText="Montant_Demander" 
                                  SortExpression="Montant_Demander" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Durée" HeaderText="Durée" SortExpression="Durée" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Pourcentage,Taux" HeaderText="Pourcentage,Taux" 
                                  SortExpression="Pourcentage,Taux" />
                          </Columns>
                             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#F2E488" Font-Bold="True" />
                      </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Although I responded to this question, I just read me too the default value of the ConvertEmptyStringToNull property is null. If possible you can check with the Profiler from Management Studio to see what SQL construct is sent to the server.

Comment: thanks a lot @Adrian Iftode can you pllzz be more specific

Comment: YES i change it to ConvertEmptyStringToNull  but i steel have the same problem

Comment: Like I said, true is the default value so this doesn't change the things. Go with Profiler and see what SQL is generated.

Comment: can give a lesson fr the Profiler

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx

Comment: tnks duddddde @Adrian Iftode... it helps me somuch ...
when i trace the code i found it fill the proccuder like this :
exec rechercherGIACetAffiche @nomgiac=N'GIAC1-IMME',@nom=N'--Sélectionner le type--',@par=N'456789'

i have a combobox with a a default --Sélectionner le type-- but an empty in the value . that why it fill with this value : --Sélectionner le type--
so now i just want to know how to make the default value in combobox  to null

Comment: put the value of the first item to "". <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="--Selectionner .."